# Possibility for a measure to ignore slicers in powerBI without editing interactions

Tags: powerbi, dax

As the title says, is it possible for a measures values not to change by any means? It's not possible for me to edit interactions with the slicer as the graph contains other measures.

F.eks. If I have a Slicer with dates December, January and February, and I select January the measure should still show data for all 3 months.

I'm hoping there's some DAX function which allows this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the filter context within a measure.

For example, if you had a calculation that summed revenue,

```
= SUM(Sales[Revenue])
```

Then you could modify it to look something more like this:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Revenue]), ALL(Sales[Date]))
```

This would clear the slicer's filter and return the sum over all dates.

Comment: Would this work with multiple tables in the calculation? e.g. SUM(Sales[Revenue]/Products[Rating]), ALL(Sales[Date]), ALL(Products[Date]) ?

Comment: @vandelay I believe so.

Comment: alright, if I may ask one more thing. Can this be done aswell with a filter that says IN {"December"; "January"; "February"}, and leave out the 9 other months?

Comment: @vandelay That sort of thing is certainly possible using `FILTER`, but there may be better ways using time intelligence functions like `DATESQTD`. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry for not going into greater detail. I will try and update my question as soon as I have time. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I tried with your formula for one table. But it does not work. When filtering January out the measure still adjusts to it.

Comment: @vandelay in your comment you have SUM but use two different tables inside the SUM, i don’t think that is allowed